# How to prevent '+' in form data being replaced by space when using PyQt4 QNetworkAccessManager.post() method

Tags: qt, http, post, pyqt, qtnetwork

My goal is to post some http form data, consisting of a `key` and `value`, using Python 2.7 and the `PyQt4.QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager.post()` method.

That in itself is not a problem.

The problem is that my `value` is a string that contains a `'+'`, e.g. `'a+b c'`, and I need that to remain a `'+'`, but the `post()` method converts this into a space, so in the raw request my example value becomes `'a b c'`.

Does anyone know if there is some (preferably easy) way to prevent this from happening?

A minimal example is provided below:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, QtNetwork

def slot_close(reply_obj):
    print 'request sent by manager.post():\n'
    print reply_obj.readAll()
    reply_obj.deleteLater()
    app.quit()

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

request = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(QtCore.QUrl('http://httpbin.org/post'))
request.setHeader(QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest.ContentTypeHeader,
    'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')

manager = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager()
manager.finished.connect(slot_close)

form_data = QtCore.QUrl()
form_data.addQueryItem('my_key', 'a+b c')
urlencoded_form_data = form_data.encodedQuery()

# Show that the urlencoded_form_data still has a '+'
print 'urlencoded_form_data:\n{}\n'.format(urlencoded_form_data)

manager.post(request, urlencoded_form_data)

app.exec_()
```

Note that e.g. the `requests.post()` method does achieve my goal, with much less effort to boot, but unfortunately I need to use QtNetwork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative would be explicilty encode the query items like this:

```
formdata.addEncodedQueryItem('my_key', QUrl.toPercentEncoding('a+b c'))
```

Note that, strictly speaking, if the key could contain non-ASCII or reserved characters, the first argument should be encoded in the same way. The [toPercentEncoding](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qurl.html#toPercentEncoding) function gives you complete control over exactly which characters are encoded, and by default, it will do the right thing. But also note that [addEncodedQueryItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qurl.html#addEncodedQueryItem) does not do any checking of its own, so it's up to the caller to ensure both arguments are encoded properly.

Answer (score 0):

Although I was looking for something more elegant, one option that works is to replace the plus-sign in the urlencoded string by its escaped version. For the example above, that would be:

`urlencoded_form_data.replace('+', '%2B')`

Comment: `formdata.addEncodedQueryItem('my_key', QUrl.toPercentEncoding('a+b c'))`.

Comment: Thanks @ekhumoro, that is exactly what I was looking for. Yours would be the accepted answer.

Comment: Glad it was helpful. I expanded my comment into an answer in case anyone else finds it useful.